# Restoring Facebook session in Android throws UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: android, facebook, session

I am trying to restore user session inside my application. For that I call :

```
Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(ctx);
```

Most of the time it works fine. But sometimes I get :

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to open an already opened session.
```

Edit :

I've add this check :

```
    Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (activeSession!=null && activeSession.isOpened()){
        return activeSession;
    }
    activeSession = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(ctx);
```

and it did not help

Does anybody have a hint how to tackle that problem?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

As the

> openActiveSessionFromCache

works like following: "Create a new Session, and if a token cache is available, open the Session and make it active without any user interaction".

So it should be better if you check if the session is open or not before calling openActiveSessionFromCache. you can use

> isOpened()

Comment: I am checking if session is open before and it did not help. See the edit part.

Comment: Is it the same error? Could you please log the activeSession.getState to inform us actually when it is not working. I would rather use the suggestion of https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/640/ when it comes to load the session. Also please inform us about the session call back, you are applying.

Answer (score 1):

Use this line of code when facebook session is not in opened state.

```
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (!state.isClosed()) {
            Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(ctx);
        }
    }
};
```